# How to Resolve Status 401 in HTTP Post Request Python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-headers, http-authentication

I am trying to make an http post request in Python. The http that I am posting to requires an authorization. For security, I have replaced the real url, data and authorization. When I run the code below with the correct url, data body and authorization I get status 401. That would imply that the authorization is not correct. Is there another way I should be adding authorization, headers and body to my http post request so that the post is successful? The authorization password is correct and works in Postman, so it's contents is not the issue--I'm wondering if the format is. Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    
    def post():
            url = 'http://somelongurl'
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('Authorization', 'PASSWORD')
            data = {"ProductID" : "ABCDEFG",
                    "ClientID": "10000",
                    "SerialNumber": "1234567890"}
            req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=auth)
            return req
```

Comment: different portals may use different methods so there is hard to answer for this kind of question without real url or with link to documentation. If you have working solution in `postman` then you can use special function in `postman` to generate code in different languages - it can also generate code for python. Postman doc: [Generating client code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved by including the authorization in the headers and changing the data as type json as follows: https://postimg.cc/3y7B6fvL

Comment: if you use `json=` in `reaquests` then it should automatically add header with `application/json`